# my computer is turning off all peripherals after a few minutes of use, how to solve it?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, screen

I've been using Ubuntu for years and never had any problems, but a couple of hours ago my computer turned off all peripherals, and now every time I restart it, it turns off all the peripherals again after about 10 minutes of use, has how to solve?

almost all peripherals are turned off, with the exception of headphones, including the monitors, keyboard and mouse, making it impossible to use the computer for work or anything else

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: This sounds like a typical over heating problem or your monitor may have gone bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install **powertop**, execute it with "sudo powertop", go with the Tabulator key to the right side to the second last column. There you can see which USB-Device (and other devices) can switch to a power-saving-Mode.

Go with up/down to the USB-Device and with space you can switch the function from power-saving to not power saving.
(the page-refresh of powerop is a bit slow)

**If you want to have remote-control over your computer install ssh:**

sudo apt install openssh-server openssh-client

Then you possibly have access to your PC over the terminal.
From an other PC or from your smartphone via the App "Termux".

There you can enter: ssh yourusername@your-PC-ip

Example: ssh arthur@192.168.0.12

Possibly you can find something in the Log-Files in the directory /var/log/kern.log or /var/log/syslog

It is more easy to navigate with midnight Commander.
(sudo apt install mc)

But, this could be an Hardware-Error too.